# Using TeamCity, how do I build a specific change?

Tags: teamcity, perforce

I'd like to build a specific change. I can see the change in the TeamCity change log, but can't see a way to initiate a build from that point in time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's `...` button just next to the `Run` one — it opens "Run Custom Build" dialog, where you can find "Changes" tab to select desired change to run a build with.